# Go interface using `var` keyword?

Tags: go, go-interface

I am referring to the code in this link: [Interfaces in Golang](https://geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-golang)

Under the "Type assertions" section, the first piece of code has a line like so in the main function: `var val interface {} = "Geeks for Geeks"`

[image]

I did not understand this syntax. Usually, we create an interface type at the package level like

```
type some_interface interface {
    // methods
}
```

and then create a variable of this interface type `var s some_interface` for use. What does this line actually do? Is it an "anonymous `interface`" (like anonymous `struct`). What is the use of declaring an interface using this method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: The statement `var val interface {} = "Geeks for Geeks"` uses a *"type literal"*, rather than a declared type, to define the type of the variable `val`. You could just as well do `type E interface{}` and then `var val E = "Geeks for Geeks"` and the only difference would be that one has a named type and the other doesn't. But, since these are interface types, named/unnamed matters little if at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is an [empty interface](https://go.dev/tour/methods/14), basically any type.

> **The empty interface**
>
> The interface type that specifies zero methods is known as the empty
> interface:
>
> interface{}
>
> An empty interface may hold values of any type. (Every type implements
> at least zero methods.)
>
> Empty interfaces are used by code that handles values of unknown type.
> For example, fmt.Print takes any number of arguments of type
> interface{}.